# mat-date-range-input Locale Configuration Not Working

Tags: forms, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

good afternoon,

I am using the mat-date-range-input and I am having issues with the Locale in Angular. In the app-module.ts, I added { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'pt-BR' }, but even so, the date field only accepts dates in the American format, as shown in the screenshot below.

Does matDatepickerParse not work when the application has a different locale than the default?

[image: start date with Today]

startDate: [new Date()],

[image]

After manually editing without using the date picker.

[image]